# Wierd behaviour int Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have been studying JS and experimenting with async behaviors'. I wrote the following code.

```
console.log("Program started");
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsSync(val))
// console.log("gap");
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsASync(val))

function wait2SecondsSync(val) {
    const date = Date.now() + 2000;
    while (date > Date.now()) { }
    console.log(val);
}

function wait2SecondsASync(val) {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(val) }, 2000)
}
```

Now, I have been getting an error, `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '4')"` after printing 1 2 3 4.

1. But strangely, if introduced some code between them, like
   `console.log("gap")`. It's working as expected,
2. Also running the
   wait2SecondsASync functions alone with out it's synchronous
   counterpart  gets it working properly.

I don't know what's happening and I couldn't exactly search and find the solution for it.

Comment: you are missing a `;` - `[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsSync(val))[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsASync(val))` is NOT what you meant to do ... `[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsSync(val));[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsASync(val))` makes it better - in javascript, as much as `;` are not "required" in many places, it's best to use them where they make sense - note: the comment doesn't change anything regarding the absence of `;`

Comment: @JaromandaX, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Jaromanda X, some more details:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsSync(val))
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsASync(val))
```

These lines are interpreted as 1 statement. So the result of the first `forEach`, (which returns) undefined is *then* accessed as if it's an array using the second [1,2,3,4]`.

So this fails because the first statement is roughly

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsSync(val))[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((val) => wait2SecondsASync(val))
```

So why is it failing on `4`? This is because accessing an array like this:

```js
myArray[1,2,3,4].someThing
```

Might look weird, but `1,2,3,4` is first evaluated and is using the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator).

This operator evaluates everything in the list and finally returns the last item. So this is equivalent to:

```js
myArray[4].someThing
```

Comment: A classic example of how leaving out semicolons can lead to weird coding mistakes.  I long ago found it easier to just put all the semicolons in and never have to worry about these odd corner cases.